# AngularJS Can't create a controller in script using function controll_name

Tags: angularjs

I have an simple html code and i put an object using ng-init and displayed that details using ng-repeat its all work fine, and i add  a controller after that it seems some error

my html code is

```
<html ng-app>
..
<body>
<div ng-controller="MyFirstController">
<div ng-repeat="album in albums | filter:searchFor | orderBy:date " >
...
</div>
...
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function MyFirstController($scope){
$scope.albums =[
  { name: 'abc', title: 'Weekend' }];


}
</script>
</body>
```

Error is showing like this

```
[ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ng/areq?p0=AlbumListController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
```

I solved this problem as i added angular.module but i want to know that is there any other solution for this i somebody know please help me......

Comment: without adding angular.module you can't use angular

Comment: this is not the current state of angular.  Angular *used to* allow this kind of declaration, 2 years ago, but it no longer functions like this.  Applications that used this pattern were intended for demonstration purposes only, but didn't have access to the vast majority of angular features, and as such, have been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
..
<body>
<div ng-controller="MyFirstController">
<div ng-repeat="album in albums | filter:searchFor | orderBy:date " >
...
</div>
...
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

   var app = angular.module("myapp");
   app.controller('MyFirstController', function MyFirstController($scope){
     $scope.albums =[{ name: 'abc', title: 'Weekend' }];
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but i already mentioned this in my question ,i want to know that there is any other possibilities to add controller like js functions.

Comment: you can't without a module

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-
**Controller**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp")
.controller('MyFirstController', function ($scope) {
   // write your business logic here

   $scope.albums =[{
         name: 'abc', 
         title: 'Weekend' 
   }];
})
```

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<body>
  <div ng-controller="MyFirstController">
    <div ng-repeat="album in albums | filter:searchFor | orderBy:date " >
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

If you are using ng-controller, ng-app or other directives, controllers then it is must to write module.
**`module`** is a container act for controllers, directives, services, etc
so if you want to add or Inject these then use that container `angulr.module`.

Comment: Thanks for the response but i already mentioned this in my question ,i want to know that there is any other possibilities to add controller like js functions.

Comment: No, if you have to use controller, services, etc then module is must to use, because module behaves as a container.

Answer (score 0):

**This can help you**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.albums =[{ name: 'abc', title: 'Weekend' },{ name: 'abcd', title: 'Weekend' }];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="album in albums | filter:searchFor | orderBy:date " >
{{album.name +" "+ album.title}}
</div>
</div>
```